# Changing array on template doesn't update on route/controller

Tags: ember.js

I need multiple input fields to fill an array of ints.

This is my template and route:

```
// Route
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController() {
    this.controller.set('myArray', [1]);
    // ...
  }
}

// Template
<!-- ... -->
{{#each myArray as |element|}}
  {{input type="number" value=element}}
{{/each}}

<p>Length: {{myArray.length}}</p>
<p>First item: {{myArray.[0]}}</p>
```

When the template is first rendered, the input field has value `1` and `First item` also shows `1`, but when I change the input value to something else, `First item` still shows `1`.

I only managed to get this to work if I replace the array of ints with an array of objects, e.g. `this.controller.set('myArray', [{value: 1}]` and then use the property `value` on the template, but I'd rather avoid this if I can. Is it possible to do this with an array of ints?

Comment: `setupController` receives `controller` as the first argument. Use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with an array of ints?

Kinda. It works with objects because you're mutating a property in the object.
With numbers they are immutable, so it doesn't quite jive. What you need to do instead is to replace the item in the array.

I suggest going with the array of objects like you have.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that was the issue. I'm gonna stick with an array of object. It's not ideal but easier to deal with.